# Not sure why my program will not execute

Tags: python

I am trying to finish my homework and having the hardest time trying to figure out why my program will not execute what i want ti to print.  Can anyone look at what i have so far and tell me where i am going wrong.

```
def main ():
last_name = input("Enter last name: ')
first_name = input("Enter first name: ')
print("last name"',',"first name")
main()
```

Comment: here is the assignment so you can understand what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: "Write a program that prompts the user for two inputs, first name and last name, in that order. Then print the user’s name in the usual alphabetical format. That is last name immediately followed by a comma, a single space, and first name. Example alphabetical format: Hancock, John"

Comment: It's quite clear from the syntax highlighting what the problem is, no?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Indentation

Some of your code needs to go *inside* your function definition for `main`, which we can do by indenting it.

```
def main ():
    last_name = input("Enter last name: ')   # \
    first_name = input("Enter first name: ') #  |-- This is the content of "main"
    print("last name"',',"first name")       # /
main()                                       # This causes "main" to run
```

### 2. Quotation Marks

Your opening and closing marks need to be the same; they should either be both `"` or both `'`.

```
def main ():
    last_name = input("Enter last name: ")
    first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
    print("last name"',',"first name")
main()
```

### 3. Printing

You're trying to print the value of the `last_name` variable, then a comma, then the value of the `first_name` variable. You've made a good effort, but your syntax is off. You need commas in-between each string you want to print, but these commas *should not* be in quotes, because they're syntax, not a string. The same applies to your variable names - if you put them in quotes, Python interprets them as text, but that isn't what we want - we want their values.

When your code is changed to fix these issues, this is the result:

```
def main ():
    last_name = input("Enter last name: ")
    first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
    print(last_name, ",", first_name)
main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great explanation.  I changed my program and  execution was perfect!  Just starting out in this course and its very interesting to learn.

Comment: @DarlenePorter No problem! Please remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: i thought (") & (') meant the same

Comment: @DarlenePorter They do, but you have to close with the same one you started with. `"Foo"` and `'Foo'` are both valid, but `"Foo'` or `'Foo"` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In `input("Enter last name: ')` (and other parts of your code), your "string starter" and "string ender" (in this case, `"` and `'` are not the same characters). You should use the same character.

Also, your function code is not properly indented.

You're also printing "last name" as a string and not as the variable.

An example of printing a variable using the `print()` method would be:

```
# what you want to do
> a = "test"
> print(a)
test

# what you did
> a = "test"
> print("a")
a
```

You're also not concatenating your strings properly. You can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings in Python (you can also do this in your `print()` function!)

Answer (score 0):

This is what it could look like:

```
def main ():
    first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
    last_name = input("Enter last name: ")
    print(last_name + ", " + first_name)
main()
```

- Either use double (`"`) or single (`'`) quotes.
- Indent your code properly.
- In your print call, pass the variables correctly.

Comment: That's not the only problem with his code. In any case, this is homework and straight-up fixing his code probably isn't for the best.